# Firebug shows slow waiting times

Tags: tomcat

Looking at my Net tab in Firebug, I see that some requests have Waiting times above 5 seconds. This is unexpected since I'm running Tomcat with 2 - 10 GB of RAM (-xms and -xmx settings). Additionally, I'm the only user sending HTTP request to this Linux server.

I’m Using Apache and Tomcat. Static, as well as Dynamic, requests are taking a long time to load (5 seconds or more).

Where should I look in Apache or Tomcat to find out what’s causing the slow waiting times?

**EDIT** For the tomcat6 process, using the `top` command, should I be concerned about the 10.8g figure under the column, VIRT? My RES column is set to 875m.

Comment: Apache comes with a tool called `ab` (or [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)) - can be a simple way of generating requests to your server to see if there are any obvious problems that can be diagnosed. A long waiting time could indicate a back-end database connection being queued by the Tomcat application (but not Tomcat itself)? But really cannot accurately speculate on what may be causing the problem. Are there synchronisation locks in your Tomcat application?

Comment: Can you describe your apache/tomcat setup? How are they talking to each other? Have you enabled logging both in apache and in tomcat? Do you see the requests coming in very closely on tomcat and on apache?

Comment: Turn on access logging in tomcat and apache.  Couple things, try using mod proxy and setting min/max for JVM.  Also, make sure you are not using htaccess files for your Apache instance which is just sending traffic to Tomcat.

Comment: @Tonin - Apache is the web server that sends dynamic requests to Tomcat via mod_jk.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is install [psi probe](https://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/). It allows realtime inspection of the tomcat server, including memory usage and patterns, etc. It should give you some great insight into what is taking so long.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, kormoc. Are there any high-level checks you advise before diving into the install?

Comment: Not offhand. It could be so many different things that just installing and bouncing around in it looking to see if anything stands out is the first thing I would do.